# How make expression with multilines?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I forgot how work with expressions. But I need multilines

```
    Expression<Func<Location, string>> f = location =>
    {
        string phone = location.Phone;
        PhoneNumberHelper.TryFormat(location.Phone, out phone);
        return phone;
    };
```

> Error 2   A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted
>   to an expression tree

Comment: If this is about entity framework or like, please mention in question. It matters.

Comment: That duplicate is really "Why can't I use multiline lambdas with entity framework". It just says that you can't convert them to expressions. It doesn't cover why you can't convert them to expressions outside of the LINQ context. Of course I suspect the answer is the trivial "Expressions can't do that" but I'm sure more insight into this can be given.

Comment: @Mediator - see the deleted answer by Sriram for a good way to work around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can't do that in this way.

For more information how to make multi-statement expression look at [Expression Trees (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397951%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) section Creating Expression Trees by Using the API.